# eloquent multiple relation filter

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

have an issue with eloquent. Have request

```
$item = Store::select('id','name')
    ->with(['product.cart' => function ($query) use($cartWhere) {
       $query->where($cartWhere);
    }])
    ->whereHas('product.cart', function ($query) use($cartWhere) {
       $query->where($cartWhere);
    })
    ->get();
```

and middle chain *product*  from *product.cart* I receive this

```
select * from `products` where `products`.`store_id` in (2, 3, 4) and `products`.`deleted_at` is null
```

But why eloquent ignore my *->whereHas* filter? Store filtered right, cart filter right, but product ignore it. how I can make that I receive an only product that needs me (exist in cart). Cart table has product_id  foreign key

Can I make this via eloquent? or I need to use raw SQL and make this manually?

---

EDIT v1: Additional info

product table has column  *store_id*
cart table has column  *product_id*,*quantity*,*site_id*,*user_id*,*id*

*$cartWhere* variable

```
$cartWhere['site_id'] =$current_site_id;
$cartWhere['user_id'] = $user_id;
```

Comment: What is in $cartWhere?

Comment: Your just passing a value to the where, you need to set the field where the database have to compare with : $query->where('field', $cartWhere);

Comment: To see how the whereHas acts, you need to look in the query on the store table and im not certain what your question is, what is it you actually are trying to achieve?

Comment: i need that in relation **product.cart" make collection like  store->product that only in cart(by cart filter)->cart with filter